# How to solve Recurrence relation: $T(n) = T(n/3) + T(n/5) + n$

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations, recursion

Given the following: $T(n) = T(n/3) + T(n/5) + n$

The aim is to find the upper bound of this solution.

I have tried to solve this using Master's Theorem, but this does not apply for this problem.

My next best options would be Substitution or Iteration, but I am having troubles finding examples similar enough to follow these methods to solve this relation.

If I were to make a "guess" to use for substitution method I would use $T(n) \leq cn$ but after working through the problem I am unable to reach any sort of a solution

Comment: T(n)< T(5n/15)+T(3n/15)+n < 2T(5n/15)+n....try from there.

Comment: I'm sorry, I know I have much to learn. Is there a source which I can refer to that will help me get to the step you have provided? Additionally, I'm still not sure where to begin from there

Comment: Algeboy's approach was to reduce the two terms to one, making it easier to find a series expression for the upper bound using iteration.

Comment: Okay I haven't expanded out into iteration. But If were going to take the original and produce `T(n)< T(5n/15)+T(3n/15)+n < 2T(5n/15)+n` What is stopping me from being able to say `2T(5n/15) + n = 2T(n/3) +n` and from here using master's theorem?

Comment: $+1$ for showing effort

Comment: @willingToLearn:  that is a good approach assuming Master's theorem fits that case.  Round up to a simpler form and solve that form is fine as long as the bound you get is acceptable.  Here any bound at all is OK because no limit was set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's check if 
\begin{equation}
 T(n) = \frac{15}{7}n
\end{equation}
is a solution for our recursion. 
\begin{align}
 T(n) &= \frac{15}{7}n \\
 T(\frac{n}{3}) &=\frac{1}{3} \frac{15}{7}n\\
 T(\frac{n}{5}) &=\frac{1}{5} \frac{15}{7}n
\end{align}
So
\begin{equation}
 T(\frac{n}{3}) + T(\frac{n}{5}) + n 
 =
 \frac{1}{3} \frac{15}{7}n +
 \frac{1}{5} \frac{15}{7}n
 +
 n 
\end{equation}
which is 
\begin{equation}
 T(\frac{n}{3}) + T(\frac{n}{5}) + n 
 =
 \frac{3}{7}n + \frac{5}{7}n + n
 =
 \frac{8+7}{7}n
 =
 \frac{15}{7}n
 =
 T(n)
\end{equation}
So
\begin{equation}
 T(n) = \frac{15}{7}n
\end{equation}
is indeed a solution.

Comment: So by making the guess of 15/7 you were able to push it through both instances of the function and prove your guess equates out to be the same? With that you're able to say "(15/7)n is negligible for larger n and simplify it to O(n)?" Thank you for the example of using a substitution on this type of a problem.

Comment: @willingToLearn  yes you are right